# Interference of coherent electromagnetic waves in two dimensions?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, interference

Interference of two coherent but mutually perpendicular electromagnetic waves whose electric field vectors are given by

$$E_{1} =E_{0} \cos (\omega  t) \widehat{i} $$

$$E_{2 } =E_{0} \cos (\omega  t + \phi) \widehat{j} $$

I know that the intensity is given by

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{0} \langle  E^{2} \rangle, $$

but I know how to calculate the intensity only in case of one dimensional interference.

What will be the total intensity in this case?

Comment: Hint: take the magnitude of the sum of the two vectors.

Comment: please use mathjax

Comment: @probably_someone! Do you mean $  \ E_{1}^2  +  E_{2}^2 $  i.e since the vectors are perpendicular the vectors won't interfere and their intensities will just get added up?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment,

> Do you mean  $E^2_1+E^2_2$ i.e since the vectors are perpendicular the vectors won't interfere and their intensities will just get added up?

yes, that is precisely the case.